# Azure worker role hangs on publish with error in Diagnostics

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

After updating to Azure SDK 2.6 (from 2.5.1) I have not been able to publish my Azure Worker Role instance.  It had been working previously with the 2.5.1 SDK.  The worker process fails to start in Azure and hangs with the status of:

> Busy (Waiting for role to start... Application startup tasks are running. [2015- 06-02T23:27:56Z] Last role error: exit code - 0, exit time - [2015/06/02,  23:27:20.218])

The worker process does make use of Azure Diagnostics - configured in my service definition file like:

```
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics"/>
</Imports>
```

and I do see an error in the Event Log of the worker VM:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'DiagnosticPlugin-ShutdownEvent' is denied.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle..ctor(Boolean initialState, EventResetMode mode, String name)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Launcher.Program.MainImpl(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Launcher.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I'm just not sure how to correct the issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Diagnostics Module should no longer be present in either SDK 2.5 or 2.6 of Azure deployments.  Azure Diagnostics in SDK2.5+ world is now configured as an extension.  (Diagnostics v1.3 version)

Here is more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/